# jQuery Animate() Doesn't Stop Animating or Complete its Task

Tags: jquery, animation, events

I'm trying to make a smooth progress bar with jquery, and make every skill bar load only if it's being viewed in the screen, eventually all is fine, but the problem is that the `animate()` method doesn't get done animating and it causes styling problems by adding `overflow: hidden;` to the element .
That's my code, i don't know if i'm doing something wrong .

```
    var progressBars = $('.progress_bar .progress_animate');

    // Loop Through Every Element .
    progressBars.each( function() {
        var el        = $(this),
            origWidth = el.data('width'),
            skillPerc = el.parents('.bm_skill').find('.skill_perc');

        // Set The Element Width To 0 .
        el.width(0);
        // Set The Element Percentage Width To 0 & Make it Transparent .
        skillPerc.width(0).css( 'opacity', '0' );

        // Make Changes On The Scroll Event .
        $(window).on( 'scroll', function() {
            var topOffset = $(window).scrollTop(),
                bottomOffset = topOffset + $(window).height();

            // Check if The Element is Being Viewed In The Screen .
            if ( bottomOffset > el.offset().top ) {
                el.animate({
                    width: origWidth
                }, 1500 );

                skillPerc.animate({
                    width: origWidth,
                    opacity: '1'
                }, 1500 );
            }
        } );
    } );
```

Comment: You need to use [stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: Once the user scrolls through an element, then it will always satisfy that condition.. Is that the wanted behavior? I think you should create a jsfiddle, so that we can better help you.

Comment: @Bla... The Task must done once, when the element is viewed it get loaded to it's specific width . i'll create a jsfiddle .

Comment: @Bla... This is The jsfiddle file http://jsfiddle.net/13k2aqbf/20/ Now you Can see what happens, and to see clearly, please open the inspector to see how the animation react after finishing its task and thanks  for being Helpful .

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the main issue here is because you use percentage instead of pixel for setting the width.. Thus, try converting the `90%` into pixels, then it will fix your problem. For example, you can try `width: '500px'` and see the result.

As a side note, you don't want to always trigger the `animate` function once the user scrolls through the divs.. So, you can add another condition, like `&& el.width() == 0`.

Hope it answers your question.. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/13k2aqbf/40/

Comment: Thanks Man For Your Help, please can i let the animation work without applying the overflow: hidden;

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about that. But, you can check the note about the `overflow` here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Actually, once the animation is finished, then the overflow will be gone..